# HTC U Ultra: Disable startup sound

Tags: audio, htc

How can I disable the startup sound? I tried the app [Silent Boot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antweb.silentboot), this has no effect on the device. Is there a file I can delete or rename to get rid of the sound?

Comment: "Is there a file I can delete or rename to get rid of the sound?" - only if you're rooted. I think just silencing the volumes should be enough to also silence the startup sound, though.

Comment: check in settings for power on sounds, and check whether there's any option to disable boot sound.

Comment: Silencing the volume is not enough, the startup sound stays.